# Nginx. Redirect depending on parameters in an request (get, post, json)

Tags: nginx, redirect, parameters

We have an API on backend. In requests to the API we pass method names. Depending on the method name we need to redirect the request to a specific Golang app.
For instance, there are two methods - "dostuff1" and "dostuff1".
Here we pass method names in URLs:
https://example.com/api?method_name=dostuff1
https://example.com/api?method_name=dostuff2

If method name "dostuff1" is passed, redirect to http://localhost:3000/dostuff1 (Golang app)
If method name "dostuff2" is passed, redirect to http://localhost:3001/dostuff2 (Golang app)

The problem is that method name may be passed not in URL only (via GET-request), but also via json in the request body, or via POST-request.
Is it possible in NGINX to capture method name passed in GET, POST or json and redirect to the correct app.
Thank you.

Tried to google some examples, but found none.